# Non-System disk or disk error but HD works on bootable USB

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, bios, usb-boot

So I have a used HP Computer with two hard drives. I installed Ubuntu on one of them and the second one is used like an external drive.

Ever since the pc sometimes struggles with booting and poops up a Non-System disk. I used to think it might be a USB drive that is pluged, and a simple reboot usually did the trick.

No since the Computer had a power outage it does not boot anymore at all. Everytime I turn it on I end up in an `Non-System disk or disk error`. I turned off everyting in the boot order except the internal HD but it didn't change anything.

I first assumed that my HD died and let the DPS Self-test run in my BIOS. There it showed that both HDs have a disk error. (`Test failed, Drive replacement recommended`)

Then I inserted the USB that I used to install Ubuntu and allowed boot from USB.

The USB booted and let me access both my HDs. I even was able to copy files around.

So next I thought maybe just the Ubuntu installation got corrupted so I did a new install choosing to format the drive (the Ubuntu installation noticed that Ubuntu was already installed on the drive).

The installation went through but when I tired to boot the HD again I run in the same error.

What can I do to make this run again? Do I just replace the Motherbord or how do I get the BIOS to do its job again. (I tried to apply the default settings but nothing changed)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Per your description and test results, it sounds like your disks are failing, not your motherboard.  I'd replace your hard drives first.  Failing drives will work randomly like you're seeing.

Comment: As @essjae suggests, it's likely the main (system) HDD. You could try switching drives, making the secondary bootable, and then recover anything possible from the old primary. Your test from USB was a good diagnostic!

Comment: Thank you guys! I ordered HDDs and will install them and try to move everything over.